# Unable to mark file as executable

Tags: 11.10, permissions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to 'chmod' on an NTFS ( or FAT32 ) partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-to-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition)

Using ubuntu 11.10 64bit. Unable to mark files as executable if the files are in windows partition. But, working ok on home folder. Can't tick the checkbox saying "allow executing file as program". Tried the command line option. But, no luck. I can write files on the windows partitions but cant change permissions of a file or folder.

Answer (score 0):

To use linux permissions, edit `/etc/fstab`, add an entry for your windows partition

```
# command line
sudo -e /etc/fstab

# graphical
gksu gedit /etc/fstab
```

use the "permissions" option, similar to this

```
UUID=12102C02102CEB83 /media/windows ntfs-3g auto,users,permissions 0 0
```

Change your uuid and mount point accordingly.

List your uuid with

```
sudo blkid
```

Comment: Since its a duplicate, there is no need to keep this around here.